# Не работает звук ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, аудио, bluetooth

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемами со звуком на ubuntu 20.04? Не работает звук: ни наушники через bluetooth, ни через джек колонки.

---

Результат выполнения команды `lsof`:

```
$lsof /dev/snd/*
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/125/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() nsfs file system /run/docker/netns/default
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a498673873a94c0b0968a4536f58a12e6d22b2c91ab694bbc44bb7cb32f753d9/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/a2fea8ba4ca3659d682a9ed9796432d6bd8c335f8b25fdbf14fa1e309875caa3/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4efe2f54573fa42375f5ebb6b173c004af6c2dc92bfc719ab2256851e2600a6b/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/24c4e48803d2c384636e9932e23354b0d8722401eaf82edfba082ade06eb1107/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ad0a32ed55ee00fbcf409b14c66c7de6579c5d297302a1f0acacf7625f641e1/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b74648297515e2154cfe56b8a9f54b2b476347f3b52d0a2d74a0bfef51a792a/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/e8085ea9dc67160ffdea892789c0b75e7172c27adb9b1a121f2ac634a0fee259/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/79ff8f3f1e43ae977c83e8ad00ec2f9cda2f64479ce38ba823380553104483f5/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f1b31a041f46be9386a1f57cd178e158e6eeeaf00e9ce851c3971ec236940e6d/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/0c877d821ad2081fb320b989f47c8adcbd16aae94a180f33ce4ebefbcdea1e0d/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2f8b1f60383d487c0bef6d6474fc897c3644bf0c2536e538b2a3f40fc140f97b/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/77a32f1d945825a3317228f57791b89684eba14b5fef7b6caa7c3c03b4fa3286/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9e67cc2cb1d1df44f8be3c2842f6a4f671bb015d462d4c405f1b81f3727d76e5/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fae664e8c0aa2c3e1d1ecc841654cabfcaa5d48b7725bfe075e6678d09ab86b2/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a654742896e059c8384cae53e99d2e26154d27ae041f0dff53cc1c878f242399/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/45c99b410a9d0821a8c76c38c7b6aa288774e3ab8b5e33745c44aa0604251c46/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ea7d0722d37331b8bfef58485d43e6a70ade3b9a2001d4ad4947399503dc6cb0/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/23d63d98fd3b4ef9e8108e91343b889a42f5467d35684c8ca65eaf2c2e0c6796/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/30057b95de763cb530125b26f47b31422f329b8f2a4784a0352bd4ae6c45cd8e/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe5ccdef4ae2edc812ebb6cc66037f51e2961c17aa6371ffc9df041a4249cc3d/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/16cccd003b6fa70e0a05c7fb45cf9b74674ef5044cef194a64a285a0aefdfe0f/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/1f48d47fc27f87b05a3eb54fdc757c3a398cee7c1acac2556a91f95c93819b67/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9401646ef2a8b4203f69cb8156479e1d3326ab42e411f0089cabf564301636d9/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/25365292e768ac2db35dd9499458ec166c47ad93d713c3c6d956c4f6cc947391/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/780ed36ec390ea9644ccf23fb8a5b86a23e8ee4b5b67fe3007b1b89da51a7e8b/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/adeb4b39b6e800e9ff592596ec714bad908b3f8e003704852486e6b6c844bd86/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/66e513476efa1d6a5635ecd3632e18000d0ff19e15d4fe8507b26051ef9834e7/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() overlay file system /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2b3e93070246cdd7b3450e3322d56b15890ef7f25f76d664497c3fca360d08d1/merged
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/d2bf086cd3a503693eca4685e24da0f6f95967ee82e99aca5eb11912312214cf/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/88d3d5b6c4a2eb2e7c0bf8c2ee4df7a573b9636813ecf67eb2bcd4d3a752703b/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/18109d67f99a8b4c3a225f89c8b7d3a8ac4dee31fdd75c9e947fcb76064b5ae5/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/189fd9dcc17e6543d0ac7bf0c2bd0ee4e552842f7bed9040f2989444ab57d5f3/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/14a60a2bf6a8a017c8fdcfd279ffb92d84283f040d0dd7ec676f8b510b907460/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/f9f06d56a4d21294229a8c9af0e284fdcc3e5c63c6b86dd95e9dcbd4c2181e77/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/f893f0757db6acd8bb19b8b3785f80437f0914d39594c72b2ed3eca776a31dff/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/085a078885dbc82bf99e17b537a974ce161498abbdabb946b63ca534d5b589cb/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/07eb64362a75a8645538f6661c3146952d21c10a128e4f2c9062e28548f19eae/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/79abaf0ce9a64e76fa025f743f5f720d3b9358ec7ea0dd4acb4e998f29631431/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/ed53672250feb04c04d24a68b3decf123cf0a3217c263f7d62c15fa51333171e/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/docker/containers/1e9f4020eb898cbdf7afb7f4517b73ea6c919e8213bf1f61f56a75ba02408a34/mounts/shm
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND      PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pulseaudi 837247   r4   16u   CHR  116,6      0t0  494 /dev/snd/controlC2
pulseaudi 837247   r4   18u   CHR 116,10      0t0  527 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 837247   r4   23u   CHR 116,12      0t0  538 /dev/snd/controlC1
```

Дополнение:

Возможное описание проблем...

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=323823
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1886341

Нашёл утилиту: `lspci`, которая выводит список всех шин. Но я не нашёл `audio`. Т.е. результат выполнения `sudo lspci | grep Audio`:

```
0c:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
0e:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
```

---

в 99% случаях блютуз и вайфай адаптеры - интел

и  нормально работают под линуксом они почему-то только после ручной настройки драйверов

Comment: возможное решение проблемы: почистить конфиг pulseaudio `rm ~/.config/pulse/` и перезапустить сервис `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`

Comment: @MaximTimakov неа. У меня наушники даже не коннектятся

Comment: @hedgehogues а какой-нибудь bluez установлен/запущен?

Comment: @andreymal нет.

Comment: Ща гуглану.....

Comment: А ещё звук может банально идти не на то устройство (на HDMI например), имеет смысл поставить `pavucontrol` и посмотреть что куда идёт

Comment: `lsof /dev/snd/*` что показывает?

Comment: @MaximTimakov добавил вывод

Comment: у меня на `Debian` была похожая проблема: pulseaudio видел только HDMI. Помогла чистка конфигов.

Comment: @MaximTimakov не совсем ясно, а что же видит `pulseaudio`

Comment: Как я у себя определил что проблема в `PulseAudio`: настроил один из плейеров на вывод звука через `ALSA`